# Django, abstract base class without autofield?

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to define a new `_id` autofield in one of the derived classes.

Simply specifying `_id` field for the derived class results in an error "
A model can't have more than one AutoField."

```
class Base(models.Model):
   class Meta:
      abstract = True

class Derived(Base):
   _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Can you specify when its raise an error? I have same configuration in my project which is working fine :P

Comment: @Darshit thanks for the input, I guess then it's because Derived class was created with django-provided 'id' field and i'm trying to add _id field as well. i'll try to see

Comment: yeah that was it.. Thank you!

Comment: can you make your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you specify when its raise an error? I have same configuration in my project which is working fine.